# Can I extract the type of Generic from a return type's type?

Tags: c#, generics

So I have, say, this type of method:

```
public ICollection<String> doSomething() { }
```

Currently, I'm trying to check if the return type of method is of type ICollection. However, in C#, I have to pass in a generic when I do the check. So I can't do, say, "method is ICollection".

The problem is that I don't want to restrict the type of generic when I'm checking. In Java, I could just use a wildcard, but I can't do that in C#. I've thought of trying to use the Type.GetGenericParamterContraints() and trying to stick the first result of it in ICollection's generic constraint to check, but that also didn't work. Anybody have any ideas?

```
isCollection(MethodInfo method){
    Type[] ret = method.ReturnType.GetGenericParametersContraint();
    Type a = ret[0];
    return method.ReturnType is ICollection<a>;
}
```

EDIT: Added what I tried.

Comment: It doesn't like when I don't put a constraint for ICollection.

Comment: The runtime type is never of `ICollection<string>`, but of concrete type list `List<string>`. So getting the types to match up is going to be tricky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's allowed to be the non-generic `System.Collections.ICollection` (which is implemented by `ICollection<T>` too) then it's simply:

```
typeof(System.Collections.ICollection).IsAssignableFrom(method.ReturnType)
```

If you only want to compare to generic `ICollection<T>` (I see no reason to, but you may have your reasons):

```
method.ReturnType.IsGenericType 
  && typeof(ICollection<>)
  .IsAssignableFrom(method.ReturnType.GetGenericTypeDefinition())
```

Note that that doesn't work if the return type is non-generic. So it won't work if there's a class that implements `ICollection<T>` but isn't generic itself. Meaning it won't catch `class Foo : ICollection<string>` but it *will* catch `class Foo<T> : ICollection<T>`.

The first way will catch both just fine though.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do:

```
MethodInfo method = ... // up to you
var returnType = method.ReturnType;

var isGenericICollection = returnType == typeof(ICollection<>);
```

Comment: `typeof(ICollection<string>) == typeof(ICollection<>)` is `false`.

Comment: Coding without an IDE...  firing up a VM

Answer (score 1):

Use [Type.GetGenericTypeDefinition()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenerictypedefinition.aspx), and compare its result with `typeof(ICollection<>)`.

So, to check if the return type of your method is an `ICollection`, you could do it like this:

```
method.ReturnType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICollection<>)
```

Btw. `method.ReturnType is ICollection<a>` will never be true because `is` checks if the type of the first operand is a subtype of the second operand. `ReturnType` is of type `Type` though which is not a subtype of some `ICollection`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Use [MethodInfo.ReturnType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getparameters.aspx) to determine the return type

```
Use the below method, call `isCollection<string>(method)` 

public static bool isCollection<T>(MethodInfo method)
{
    return method.ReturnType.Equals(typeof(ICollection<T>));
}
```

Comment: Aw crap. I just realized that I named the two methods the same. I'm really sorry about that. So, I have a medthod, "doSomething" that returns some collection, ICollection<T>(Or ArrayList or whatever). And then I have another method, isCollection, that checks if the method passed is a collection.

Note to self, get more sleep.

Comment: But when I call isCollection, won't I need to pass in a constraint for calling it? I won't have the constraint when I call it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class Program
{
    public ICollection<string> Foo() { return new List<string>(); } 
    public static bool TestType()
    {
        MethodInfo info = typeof(Program).GetMethod("Foo");

        return info.ReturnType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICollection<>);
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} is ICollection<> : {1}", "Foo", TestType());
    }
}
```

prints `Foo is ICollection<> : True`.